# Global javascript variables inside chrome.runtime API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I am passing a message from my content script to my background.js.

I want the message to alter the global variable `foo` in the below code. The message passes without issue and the first `alert()` works properly, but the second `alert()` uses the original `foo` definition.

How can I make the updated `foo` the global variable, such that the second `alert()` results in `second`, not `first`?

**background.js**

```
var foo = "first"

// Other code here...

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _) {
    foo = msg.passedMessage; // where passedMessage = "second"
    alert(foo) // "second"
});

alert(foo) // "first"
```

Comment: i didn't find any problem in this code

Comment: It's not possible. The `addListener()` callback is dependent on the occurrence of an event (on receiving a `message`) while the 2nd `alert(foo)` executes immediately without waiting.

Comment: but second alert is present in callback function. so 2nd alert will execute within callback func.